# Nested if conditions with Vlookup producing N/A instead of next conditional statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Below is my formula:

```
=IF(AND(A513="Secondary",VLOOKUP(E513,'Secondary Schedule Archive'!$A$3:$A$23,1,FALSE)),"Information",IF(AND(A513="Secondary",VLOOKUP(E513,'Secondary Schedule Archive'!$C$3:$C$23,1,TRUE)),"Floorplan","False"))
```

I am checking two pieces of criteria per if statement. However, what I am running into is that if my first condition's `VLOOKUP` does not find anything, it produced the `#N/A` value instead of simply moving to the next condition and then populating that value.

Is there a different approach that I could take or something that I can change with my existing formula so that this doesn't occur?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(first set of args),VLOOKUP(second set of args))`.

`IFERROR()` provides the value of the first argument, unless it is an error, in which case it provides the value of the second.

Comment: Can it be used with the if/and statement as well?

Comment: Yes, you can combine IFERROR with other functions. I'm not sure what your original formula was meant to achieve, but you can always use  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(first set of args),"First one not found") if you want to avoid getting a #N/A value.

Comment: `=IF(IFERROR(AND(A349="Secondary",VLOOKUP(E349,'Secondary Schedule Archive'!$A$3:$B$23,1,TRUE))),"Information","",IF(AND(A349="Secondary",VLOOKUP(E349,'Secondary Schedule Archive'!$C$3:$D$23,1,TRUE)),"Floorplan","False"))`

I tried like this and it is not working. What am I doing wrong with it?

Comment: If you want people to help you with a formula, you should tell them what you are trying to achieve, and provide sample data. "It is not working" is not much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used within your construct.

Basically, your `AND` produces not either TRUE or FALSE, but rather TRUE or #ERROR!. That comes from your `VLOOKUP`'s either producing a "result" or an #ERROR!. Since any "result" leads to the `AND` producing TRUE (assuming A513 contains "Secondary"), the `VLOOKUP` output is the only thing needing a fix.

When you wrap it in `IFERROR` with the result of an error being an output of FALSE (so like:  IFERROR(VLOOKUP,FALSE) would be the form), you have fixed the problem. It happens with both uses so you need it in both cases.

It is perfectly able to work within your `IF` and `AND` functions.

Comment: `=IF(IFERROR(AND(A349="Secondary",VLOOKUP(E349,'Secondary Schedule Archive'!$A$3:$B$23,1,TRUE))),"Information","",IF(AND(A349="Secondary",VLOOKUP(E349,'Secondary Schedule Archive'!$C$3:$D$23,1,TRUE)),"Floorplan","False"))`... I tried like this and it is not working. What am I doing wrong with it?